# MassTransit ScheduleRecurringMessage vs ScheduleRecurringSend

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net, masstransit

My question is: why ScheduleRecurringMessage is obsolete? 
If so, how can I schedule publishing recurring messages? 
P.S new ScheduleRecurringSend method will **send** instead of **publishing** message.

Comment: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/647

Comment: Yes, I saw this article, it says : "ScheduleMessage", is a legacy method use
"ScheduleSend", but it's totally different functionality: 
Publishing - copy of the message is delivered to each subscriber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using RabbitMQ, you can use the `ScheduleRecurringSend` method, you just need to specify the destination address as the exchange address for the message type. There is also a way to get the destination address from the HostSettings on the Host, if you don't want to risk formatting it yourself.

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/master/src/MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport/SchedulePublishExtensions.cs#L430

(this shows it from the ConsumeContext, but the host settings are on the host configured in the bus factory)

That should get you where you need to be, from a recurring schedule perspective.